# Can I go back and change my reward from the Color Dungeon?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I finished the Color Dungeon and picked the red mail so I could do more damage, but now I am wondering if I made the right choice. Can I go back and switch for the blue, to have more defense? Or am I stuck with my choice?

If I go back, do I have to do the dungeon again? It was super hard, so I don't want to risk it if it doesn't get me anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can switch colors.

In fact, you can essentially skip the whole dungeon if you want to change your choice. You can warp from the dungeon entrance to the boss fight room, and you do not have to fight the boss a second time. Simply speak to the fairy queen in the next room and can choose red, blue, or even green (regardless of previous choices).

Comment: Fun Fact: In the Switch version, you can also change back to the green tunic. In the original versions, you could not